# Running listener in a background service in android

Tags: android

I am needed to receive data from usb serial port whenever some data is written on it.

For this i have created a service that has a onread listener which reads data from serial port when data is available.

I am appending a textview with the received data in my activity. But i cannot see anything.

My service is running but not able to receive any data.

Below is my service class code.

```
public class BroadcastService extends Service {
    private static final String TAG = "BroadcastService";
    public static final String BROADCAST_ACTION = "com.example.flowtest.displayevent";
    private final Handler handler = new Handler();
    // DatabaseHandle db = new DatabaseHandle(this);
    Intent intent;
    int counter = 0;
    int i = 0, flag = 0;
    String d = "a";
    byte[] buf = new byte[5];
    byte[] start = new byte[21];
    byte[] rbuf;// updated
    String str;
    Physicaloid mPhysicaloid = new Physicaloid(this);

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        intent = new Intent(BROADCAST_ACTION);
        // mPhysicaloid.open();

    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {

        mPhysicaloid.open();

        handler.removeCallbacks(getdata);
        handler.post(getdata);
    }

    private Runnable getdata = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Log.d("service", "in service");
            mPhysicaloid.addReadListener(new ReadLisener() {

                @Override
                public void onRead(int size) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    byte[] rbuf = new byte[size];
                    mPhysicaloid.read(rbuf, size);
                    try {
                        str = new String(rbuf, "UTF-8");

                        if (str.equals(null)) {
                            flag = 0;
                            intent.putExtra("inputString", "no luck");
                            sendBroadcast(intent);
                        } else {
                            flag = 1;
                            intent.putExtra("inputString", str);
                            sendBroadcast(intent);
                        }

                        // sendBroadcast(intent);

                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }

            });

        }
    };

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // handler.removeCallbacks(sendUpdatesToUI);
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

Now my activity ,

```
private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
     public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        updateUI(intent);       
    }

    private void updateUI(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String data = intent.getStringExtra("inputString").toString();
        if(data.equals("NORMAL")){
            i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ModeScreenActivity.class);
              startActivity(i);
              finish();
        }
        else{

        }
        tvAppend(tv1,data);
    }
};
```

Comment: Please help me out. I want to use background service as the serial data will be used by many activities and i doesn't want to write onread listener in all the activities. Please help

Comment: i've tried different possible ways available on internet but still i am stuck with this problem

Comment: You should probably pursue this with the providers of "Physicaloid" first.

Comment: I am not able to add a listener in my service. When i run my listener in activity it is working fine but when i am doing the same in service on create method , i am not able to send serial data from service to activity.

Comment: Physicaloid library is working fine.

Comment: Again, you should pursue that with the creators of "Physicaloid".  Perhaps they do not support your intended usage.

Comment: ok i will , but is my procedure correct???

Answer (score 0):

You setup your read listener within the getData runnable. This means that the listener will only be valid while getData is running. Since getData terminates immediately, the listener will never get a chance to execute.

Either move the listener out of getData or have getData be a long running thread with the same lifetime as your service.